# Remove an element from a Python list of lists in PySpark DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to remove an element from a Python list of lists:

```
+---------------+
|        sources|
+---------------+
|           [62]|
|        [7, 32]|
|           [62]|
|   [18, 36, 62]|
|[7, 31, 36, 62]|
|    [7, 32, 62]|
```

I want to be able to remove an element, `rm`, from each of the lists in the list above. I wrote a function that can do that for a list of lists:

```
def asdf(df, rm):
    temp = df
    for n in range(len(df)):
        temp[n] = [x for x in df[n] if x != rm]
    return(temp)
```

which does remove `rm = 1`:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5]]
In:  asdf(a,1)
Out: [[2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

But I can't get it to work for a DataFrame:

```
asdfUDF = udf(asdf, ArrayType(IntegerType()))

In: df.withColumn("src_ex", asdfUDF("sources", 32))

Out: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method col([class java.lang.Integer]) does not exist
```

Desired behavior:

```
In: df.withColumn("src_ex", asdfUDF("sources", 32))
Out: 

+---------------+
|         src_ex|
+---------------+
|           [62]|
|            [7]|
|           [62]|
|   [18, 36, 62]|
|[7, 31, 36, 62]|
|        [7, 62]|
```

(except have the new column above appended to a PySpark DataFrame, `df`)

Any suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Spark >= 2.4**

You can use `array_remove`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array_remove

df.withColumn("src_ex", array_remove("sources", 32)).show()
```

```
+---------------+---------------+
|        sources|         src_ex|
+---------------+---------------+
|           [62]|           [62]|
|        [7, 32]|            [7]|
|           [62]|           [62]|
|   [18, 36, 62]|   [18, 36, 62]|
|[7, 31, 36, 62]|[7, 31, 36, 62]|
|    [7, 32, 62]|        [7, 62]|
+---------------+---------------+
```

or `filter`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df.withColumn("src_ex", expr("filter(sources, x -> not(x <=> 32))")).show()
```

```
+---------------+---------------+
|        sources|         src_ex|
+---------------+---------------+
|           [62]|           [62]|
|        [7, 32]|            [7]|
|           [62]|           [62]|
|   [18, 36, 62]|   [18, 36, 62]|
|[7, 31, 36, 62]|[7, 31, 36, 62]|
|    [7, 32, 62]|        [7, 62]|
+---------------+---------------+
```

**Spark < 2.4**

A number of things:

- `DataFrame` is not a *list of lists*. In practice it is not even a plain Python object, it has no `len` and it is not `Iterable`.
- Column you have looks like plain `array` type.
- You cannot reference `DataFrame` (or any other distributed data structure inside UDF).
- Every argument passed directly to UDF call has to be a `str` (column name) or `Column` object. To pass literal use `lit` function.

The only thing that remains is just a list comprehension:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, udf

def drop_from_array_(arr, item):
    return [x for x in arr if x != item]

drop_from_array = udf(drop_from_array_, ArrayType(IntegerType()))
```

Example usage:

```
df = sc.parallelize([
    [62], [7, 32], [62], [18, 36, 62], [7, 31, 36, 62], [7, 32, 62]
]).map(lambda x: (x, )).toDF(["sources"])

df.withColumn("src_ex", drop_from_array("sources", lit(32)))
```

The result:

```
+---------------+---------------+
|        sources|         src_ex|
+---------------+---------------+
|           [62]|           [62]|
|        [7, 32]|            [7]|
|           [62]|           [62]|
|   [18, 36, 62]|   [18, 36, 62]|
|[7, 31, 36, 62]|[7, 31, 36, 62]|
|    [7, 32, 62]|        [7, 62]|
+---------------+---------------+
```