# Get the top two elements in a nested list - pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Let's say I have a list `L=[[a,2],[a,3],[a,4],[b,4],[b,8],[b,9]]`
Using pyspark I want to be able to remove the third element so that it will look like this:

```
[a,2]
[a,3]
[b,4]
[b,8]
```

I am new to pyspark and not sure what I should do here.

Comment: I do  not see nested lists, I see a list of tuples. And what happened to (b,9) - it is the last element, not the third but still vanished ....

Comment: [/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-list-by-index-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627435/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-list-by-index-in-python)   and   [remove-an-element-from-a-python-list-of-lists-in-pyspark-dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41624567/remove-an-element-from-a-python-list-of-lists-in-pyspark-dataframe)   and   [understanding-pythons-slice-notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: and   [how-to-remove-multiple-indexes-from-a-list-at-the-same-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303225/how-to-remove-multiple-indexes-from-a-list-at-the-same-time)  and ... some more Q all about list manipulation.

Comment: This is a Python question, not a Spark one?

Comment: Just to clarify, I need it to remove the third element of each group. Here each group is defined by the index of the nested list so letter a and letter b. Also the actions will be performed on an RDD. This means i need to use pyspark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this.
The first step is groupby `key` column and aggregate values in a list. Then use a udf to get the first two values of the list and then explode that column.

```
df = sc.parallelize([('a',2),('a',3),('a',4),
                       ('b',4),('b',8),('b',9)]).toDF(['key', 'value'])
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list, udf, explode
from pyspark.sql.types import *

foo = udf(lambda x:x[0:2], ArrayType(IntegerType()))
df_list = (df.groupby('key').agg(collect_list('value')).
                   withColumn('values',foo('collect_list(value)')).
                   withColumn('value', explode('values')).
                   drop('values', 'collect_list(value)'))
df_list.show()
```

result

```
+---+-----+
|key|value|
+---+-----+
|  b|    4|
|  b|    8|
|  a|    2|
|  a|    3|
+---+-----+
```

Comment: This worked for me. I was hoping there would be a much cleaner solution that did not require data frames. Maybe something using reduceByKey and groupBy but there does not seem to be one.Thank you!

Comment: I have one additional question. How would this solution work with three columns. I am trying to add a third column that needs to be treated the same as "value" in the solution above but the output is not being printed in the right order.

Comment: Can you elaborate the right order? did you mean ascending or descending order?

Comment: I just mean when I add another column to your example code it does not work. I added to the new value in the .agg() and also created new columns using withColumn() . When I show the list all column data is mixed up even and it no longer shows the top five.

Comment: can you edit the question and add this part with its model solution?

Comment: Hi @ashwinids, I actually managed to get it working this morning. Instead of making a third column I just combined the third piece of data with the second. Once again I appreciate the help!